# Bounded sequence $a_n=\sqrt{4+2 \sqrt{4+\cdots+2 \sqrt{4+2 \sqrt{4+2 \sqrt{4+4}}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let
$$a_n=\sqrt{4+2 \sqrt{4+\cdots+2 \sqrt{4+2 \sqrt{4+2 \sqrt{4+4}}}}}$$
the sign $\sqrt{}$ occurs $n$ times.

a) Prove, that $a_n< \sqrt{5}+1$ for all $n$.

b) Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } a_n$

*Author O.Kukush*

Comment: Note that $a_n=\sqrt{4+2a_{n-1}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove (a) by mathematical induction. $a_1$ is less than $1+\sqrt5$ by direct comparison as $a_1 = \sqrt8 < 3$ while $1+\sqrt5>3$. Let $a_n < 1+\sqrt5$. Then $4+2a_n < 6+2\sqrt5$ and taking square root on both sides (that both are positive is trivial) we obtain $a_{n+1} < 1+\sqrt5$.

It also follows that $(a_n)$ is strictly growing. You can check that by comparing $a_{n+1}^2 = 4+2a_n$ with $a_n^2$ knowing that (a) is true.

From the monotonicity and boundedness it follows that $(a_n)$ has a limit and this number, let's call it $a$, needs to be a fixed point of $\sqrt{4+2a} = a$. The only solution larger than $0$ is $1+\sqrt5$.

Answer (score 2):

For the case (b) when $n \to \infty$ we can write the following,
\begin{equation}
a_n^2 = 4 + 2a_n \\ a_n^2 - 2a_n - 4 = 0 \\ a_n = \cfrac{2+\sqrt{20}}{2} = 1 + \sqrt{5}
\end{equation}
So, it may be stated that for all other $n$, $a_n < 1 + \sqrt{5} $

Comment: You must prove that $a_n < a_{n + 1}$ for all $n.$

Comment: This is valid provided you know the limit exists.